# Transferring secret data using SSL version 3

Tags: tls

How is it secure to transfer secret company data using SSL version 3? What is the best way to send this data?

Comment: SSL3 is so outdated, it is not even worth considering answering the question. But if you transfer your data currently in the clear using SSL will be safer (a bit)

Comment: what are your requirements for sending the data? that's how you determine what's 'best'

Answer (score 3):

> how is it secure to transfer Secret company data using SSL version 3

SSLv3 is considered broken and should no longer be used. This means that an attacker with considerable resources is expected to be able to decrypt such traffic by spending lots of money. And it will only get worse, i.e. the costs of the attack will decrease.

> what is the best way to send this data?

There is no 100% security and the "best way" is whatever causes the lowest and acceptable risk given a specific effort (i.e. money spend, usability ...). How much efforts need to be done and where it is best done depends on your specific environment and the kind of data to protect.

For example you might still use SSLv3 if you are in a secure environment where the risk of somebody sniffing data is low enough. But using TLS 1.2 with modern ciphers instead of SSLv3 would reduce the risk of data compromise in case somebody is able to sniff the traffic. If this is too costly maybe because of the changes to the infrastructure involved you might try to reduce the risk instead by adding an additional encryption layer on top of SSLv3. But again, the decision what is best is specific to your environment and its restrictions.